# What does the 1 in ls(1) refer to?

Tags: command-line, unix, manpages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the parentheses and number after a Linux command or C function mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/297702/what-do-the-parentheses-and-number-after-a-linux-command-or-c-function-mean)

I see that many utilities have a number in brackets after their name, for example `ls(1)` or `symlink(7)`. What are these numbers called, and what do they reference?

Comment: I have always seen this but never cared to ask or find an answer to this. +1 for asking this question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The numbers refer to the manpage section the manpage belongs to:

> 1 Executable programs or shell commands
>
> 2 System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
>
> 3 Library calls (functions within program libraries)
>
> 4 Special files (usually found in /dev)
>
> 5 File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
>
> 6 Games
>
> 7 Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
>
> 8 System administration commands (usually only for root)
>
> 9 Kernel routines [Non standard]

(from `man man` :-) )

The reason for showing the section is mainly that there is often a manpage with the same name in more than one section, e.g. `man(1)` (the `man` command), and `man(7)` (the system of manual pages). Same for e.g. system calls (section 2,3) and commandline programs (section 1) with the same name, e.g. `unlink`.

BTW, you can use `man -a` to see man pages from all sections for a given search term.

Comment: Thanks! I think my man files must be set up wrongly. When I try to find man in section 7, I just get "No entry for man in section 7 of the manual" - and man(1) only describes how to invoke the man executable.

Comment: Well, the set of man pages is not standarized, AFAIK. So maybe your OS / installations just chose a diferent set of man pages... . What OS are you on?

Comment: The section numbers vary somewhat between unix variants. 1, 2 and 3 are firmly entrenched, others less so. The list given here is for Linux. Many systems have an `intro` man page in each section.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking at the `man` page when you see these, they are the "section" in which to look. By default, `man` pulls up the first entry it finds for a given query. However, this can cause issues where you have an entry for `crontab`, the command, and `crontab`, the system file (the command is used to edit the file). By specifying the section you want, you can tell man which you're looking for. `man man` should give you a listing of the sections, and you can select one with `man <section> <query>`, such as `man 1 ls`.