# Why are parentheses and numbers used in FreeBSD documentation?

Tags: freebsd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the parentheses and number after a Linux command or C function mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/297702/what-do-the-parentheses-and-number-after-a-linux-command-or-c-function-mean)

I just installed FreeBSD 8.2 using a DVD ISO and I'm a first time user of FreeBSD. I wonder why the documentation uses parentheses and numbers when describing certain functions. For example, here's a portion of the text from this [documentation](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-overview.html):

> Unpack the software from its distribution format (typically a tarball
>   compressed with **compress(1)**, **gzip(1)**, or **bzip2(1)**).

Notice the words compress, gzip and bzip2. Why do they put a parenthesis and a number after it? Even in the detail page of each function, they also use a parenthesis and a number such as:

```
COMPRESS(1)     FreeBSD General Commands Manual        COMPRESS(1)

NAME
     compress, uncompress -- compress and expand data

SYNOPSIS
     compress [-fv] [-b bits] [file ...]
     compress -c [-b bits] [file]
     uncompress [-f] [file ...]
     uncompress -c [file]
```

Is there any special meaning or notation about the usage of parenthesis and a number in it?

Comment: @Gareth: Are you sure the dup question can answer my question because I really a newbie? If so, thanks for pointing me to the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They indicate what manpage section the command is described in. For example, to get information about the *command line program* [read(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/read), type

```
man 1 read
```

If you are interested in the *system call* [read(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read), type

```
man 2 read
```

And if you want to know more about the *C function* [read(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read), type

```
man 3 read
```

For more information about the available sections, refer to [this excellent answer](https://superuser.com/questions/297702/what-do-the-parentheses-and-number-after-a-linux-command-or-c-function-mean/297705#297705).