# Compress files from OS X terminal?

Tags: macos, unix, compression, zip

In the Finder, there is this wonderful ability to right click on a file or directory, select compress from the drop-down, and end up with a zipped file.

Is it possible to do the same thing from the terminal?

Answer (score 225):

It's called `zip`.

This adds the file *`file`* to the archive *`file.zip`*:

```
zip file.zip file
```

Of course, to add more files, just add them as arguments to the command. Check out `man zip` for more options.

Often, you'll want to skip including those pesky `.DS_Store` files, for example compressing the whole folder *`folder`* into *`folder.zip`*:

```
zip -vr folder.zip folder/ -x "*.DS_Store"
```

Comment: whats the (1) after the word zip?

Comment: @JacobRaccuia See http://superuser.com/questions/297702/what-do-the-parentheses-and-number-after-a-unix-command-or-c-function-mean

Comment: Is it the plain old GNU zip that comes with OS X?

Comment: @mwfearnley Under macOS, it's `Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP`. https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zip.1.html

Comment: link to manpage broke .. just use `man zip` on the command line

Comment: I got an empty zip file :(

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Please ask a new question about this and include as much info as possible.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, add -r when you compress folders.

Comment: You can use -X to exclude all annoying Mac OS hidden files, not only DS_Store.

Comment: Avoid console clutter `zip -rXq f.zip f` -r Recursively -X as said @ivanzolotov -q Quiet mode;

Answer (score 54):

To compress the files **exactly** as the Finder command would compress them, use:

```
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent src_directory archive.zip
```

---

See `man ditto` for details:

> ```
>  The command:
>        ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent src_directory archive.zip
>  will create a PKZip archive similarly to the Finder's Compress function-
>  ality.
> ```

Comment: This is the best answer because it produces an identical zip, whereas CLI zip or tar is different and slightly smaller. A similar question with the same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738505/mac-os-x-compress-option-vs-command-line-zip-why-do-they-produce-different-re

Answer (score 44):

with considering the above answers,
If you want to compress a **directory** or **folder** with the `zip` command:

```
zip -r directory.zip directory
```

##### Explanation:

`zip` command for zipping

`directory.zip` is the destination file that will be created after running the zip command.

`direcotry` source folder which you want to be compressed.

`-r` flag will recursively iterate in folders and subfolders.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am looking for

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Comment: This does not preserve symlinks. eg. if you zip a .app then a symlink like `Frameworks/App.framework/Versions/Current` is just becomes a cloned directory

Answer (score 9):

There is [tar(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tar.1.html) and gzip (or bzip2 or lzma). Tar is used to roll a number of files into one archive, while the one of the other three is used to compress it.

On a command line, you will call tar with a couple of options to create an archive and gzip it.

E.g.:

```
tar -c -z -f myarchive.tar.gz -C /home/username Downloads
```

This willl ***-c*** reate a g ***-z*** ipped archive named ***-f*** ile from the ***-C*** hange-folder-to directory and will contain all files in the folder Downloads. The -C option is optional and the source-file arguments will be taken from the current folder if omitted.

For reference:
[tar tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20120831101143/http://www.apl.jhu.edu:80/Misc/Unix-info/tar/tar_2.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to compress specific files you can add multiple file names like so:

```
zip my_archive_name.zip some_file_a some_file_b some_file_c
```

and that results in an archive that only has the files specified