# Why man read don't contain any argument description in my debian?

Tags: bash, debian, command-line-arguments, read

As far as i know that `read` in bash contains many argument such as `-a -d -e -r`.
The webpage list all arguments of `read`.
[read's arguments](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/read.htm)

In my console, `man read` contains no argument on it.
I upload `man read > read.txt` into dropbox,please download it and verify.

[man read > read.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t614kmlcv00ctpr/read.txt?dl=0)

Comment: `help read` since `read` is a builtin from the shell.

Comment: The page you uploaded is headed `read(2)` where the number in parentheses is the _section_ and [section 2 is system calls not user commands/programs](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/man-pages.7.en.html)

Comment: Along with [What do the parentheses and number after a Unix command or C function mean?](https://superuser.com/q/297702/432690)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why `man read` don't contain any argument description in my debian?

Use `help read` instead.

`read` is a [bash builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html). to display options, description, you should use the `help` command. see `help help` or the [gnu documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html):

```
help

    help [-dms] [pattern]

    Display helpful information about builtin commands. If pattern is specified, help gives detailed help on all commands matching pattern, otherwise a list of the builtins is printed.

    Options, if supplied, have the following meanings:

    -d

        Display a short description of each pattern 
    -m

        Display the description of each pattern in a manpage-like format 
    -s

        Display only a short usage synopsis for each pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections

Note the 2 in `READ(2)` - that tells you're viewing something from section 2 of the man pages.

Depending on which OS you're using, the section content might differ. Please see the Wikipedia page linked above.

The content you show is the "read()" function, from basic "C" computer programming language (present already in K&R C).

The "read" you're after is described either in "man bash" or (as told in man bash) tersely by "help read".

You will also find most about bash in the Bash guides at http://www.tldp.org/ (lengthy texts, loads of examples).